# How to change styles.scss dynamically in angular 8 on fly via a styling file taken from a get api?

Tags: css, typescript, dynamic, sass, angular8

I have two angular(typescript) applications. Let's say **App1** and **App2** and both are **running**. My requirement is that when I **upload a css/scss file from App1**, it will be stored in a server via an API POST call. So I need to get that uploaded css/scss file/ contents of it  via a GET API call in App2 and change the styling of the ***running* App2** (changing the styles **dynamically**).

Is there any way which I can accomplish this?

Comment: what you tried so far?

Comment: I have done uploading the file through App1. But do not know any way to use it in App2 in runtime/ dynamically to change App2's styles